What is this cable I have? Can I use this cable as a ethernet patch cable?
I have a cable that has “NETWORK PATCH CABLE 4PR UTP CAT6E TIA/EIA-568B 072M” stamped on it.
But when I open it up, there are 8 individual cables wires. but they are not twisted pairs.
What is this cable I have?
Can I use this cable as an Ethernet patch cable?


Are the pairs really not individually twisted? It's labelled Cat6e, and it does look a bit like Cat6e; there seems to be at least some twisting in it.

You can use practically cable that has 8 individual copper cores as an ethernet cable provide you wire it up as an RJ-45 cable. I am probably oversimplifying that statement.

Looks twisted to me.

@grawity_u1686, i see what you mean.... does the degree of twisting matter? I opened up about 100cm of cable, they seem to be twisted every 5cm. The twisting is so light that opening up the protective sheaf makes the cables fall apart so a couple of pairs don't look twisted at all....

@Ramhound in the past I have heard many engineers somewhat exaggerate that "you can run ethernet down wet string" and indeed you can run almost anything over wet string  for short distances and if you don't mind it being slow or unreliable. So you are not wrong that the cable can be almost anything. Typically we go for known good cable for long term reliability and immunity from local interference.

Note, that it looks to be unshielded, so may be susceptible to electrical interference. You would expect to see some metallic foil in black section folded back. This is further evidenced by UTP (Unshielded Twisted Pair) in the labelling.

Since CAT6e isn't actually a thing, I wouldn't count on this cable performing particularly well.

If you just use 8 unshielded copper cables hosts in a rubber case, It probably won't perform well, and it well be susceptible to EMI.  It can be used for a patch RJ-45 cable.

This cable looks suspect.  Could be low quality cable bought cheaply...  If it were me, just buy proper patch cables and save yourself possible headaches down the line.

@Ramhound No, Ethernet cable always requires twisted pairs, even for patch cords. In fact, even the little bit of untwisting one must do to terminate a cable should be kept to a minimum (less than an inch).

The brown pair at the back is definitely twisted, and the pairs look to be individually shrouded with their own plastic. The required twists will depend on spacing to the other wire in the pair and other pairs of wires.
The shroud on each pair will change the requirements and the distance between pairs will be increased meaning potentially a more gentle twist.
If the cable says CAT6e then it is cable that can be used for ethernet.
